# Getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional a rgument: 'on_delete'

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, django-models, atom-editor, django-3.0

'HOw to reslove this erroe I am using Django 3.0'

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name
class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic= models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class AccessRecord(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
        date = models.DateField()

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.date)
```

I copied code of Django 1 version and I am using Django 3.0 version.

File "C:\Users\himan5hu\Documents\HTML\My_Django\first_project\first_app\models.py", line 7, in 
    class Webpage(models.Model):

File "C:\Users\himan5hu\Documents\HTML\My_Django\first_project\first_app\models.py", line 8, in Webpage topic= models.ForeignKey(Topic)

```
topic= models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), it is mandator to specify an [**`on_delete=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) for a `ForeignKey`. Before [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), it was by default `CASCADE`.

`on_delete=…` is a parameter that specifies what to do in case the target object is deleted. In case of `CASCADE` the `Webpage` will thus be removed if it points to a `Topic` that is removed.

You thus can fix this with:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic= models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AccessRecord(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date = models.DateField()

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.date)
```

You will need to alter this in existing *migration files* as well.

It might however be useful to inspec the documentation, and look if another option might be more approriate.